# Handle multiple input value change within an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, events, state

The requirement is handle the change of multiple input fields within the `handleChange()` method and the starter object that has it's own properties, so input field values should be assigned to those properties within the starter object. So far, the `handleChange()` method results [the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlQjt.png). Any ideas ? =(

Constructor:

```js
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      starter: {
        title: '',
        ingredients: '',
        price: 0
      }
    };

    this.createStarter = this.createStarter.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
```

Handle change:

```js
handleChange(evt) {
    this.setState({
      starter: {
        [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value
      }
    });
  }
```

Render:

```js
render() {
    const { t } = this.props;
    const { starter: { title, ingredients, price } } = this.state;

        <input
          className="contact-control"
          type="text"
          name="title"
          value={title}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder={t('starter-form.title')}
        />

        <input
          className="contact-control"
          type="text"
          name="ingredients"
          value={ingredients}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder={t('starter-form.ingredients')}
        />
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the existing state using object [destructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
handleChange(evt) {
this.setState({
  starter: {
    ...this.state.starter
    [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value
  }
});
```

}

Comment: const { starter } = this.state =)))